# Magento: Xdebug miss breakpoint on some method

Tags: php, magento, xdebug, breakpoints

This is something I cannot figure out:

On some circumstance like on some internal method as _costruct() (also, maybe ajax call ) Xdebug doesn't hit the breakpoint.

Any fix for that ?

Comment: if it misses then it is not called?

Comment: Hard to say. It would be great if you post some concrete scenario applicable to standard Magento installation: url and file with the breakpoint.

Comment: I will provide example soon. No Anton it is called ( die() works :P )